# How to draw function mappings (as shown in figure) in Tikz LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, mapping

How to draw these two mappings in Tikz?

Your help will will be highly appreciated.

Best,
Faizan

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you tra so far? First diagram is simple to draw with `tikz-cd` package

Comment: Look e.g. for graph in the pgfmanual (search ctan tikz), which is just one way to do it. Look also for labeling lines/pathes.

Comment: I am beginner at LaTeX. Can you send the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the tips of `tikz-cd` package applying `xy` package we have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r] \ar@{-->}@/_2.5pc/[rr]_{g \circ f} &B \ar[r] &C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the tips of `xy` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r] \ar@{-->}@/_2.5pc/[rr]_{g \circ f} &B \ar[r] &C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd drawing**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ & B\ar[rr]^g \ar@{-->}[drrr]_{h\circ g}  &  & C\ar[dr]^h \\
A \ar[ur]^f \ar@{-->}[rrrr]_{h\circ(g\circ f)} \ar@{-->}[urrr]_{g\circ f} \ar@{-->}@/_2.5pc/[rrrr]_{(h\circ g)\circ f}&  &  &  & D
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Tips arrows of `tikz-cd` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ & B\ar[rr]^g \ar@{-->}[drrr]_{h\circ g}  &  & C\ar[dr]^h \\
A \ar[ur]^f \ar@{-->}[rrrr]_{h\circ(g\circ f)} \ar@{-->}[urrr]_{g\circ f} \ar@{-->}@/_2.5pc/[rrrr]_{(h\circ g)\circ f}&  &  &  & D
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all, you made my day.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for the first mapping:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[](A){A};
\node[right of=A](B){B};
\node[right of=B](C){C};
\path[draw, -latex'] (A) -- node[above]{$f$} (B);
\path[draw, -latex'] (B) -- node[above]{$g$} (C);
\path[draw, -latex', dashed] (A) to [bend right]  node[below]{$g\circ f$} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:
[image: First mapping]

Here is the code for the second mapping:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[](A){A};
\node[above right of=A, node distance=20 mm](B){B};
\node[right of=B, node distance=20 mm](C){C};
\node[below right of=C, node distance=20 mm](D){D};
\path[draw, -latex'] (A) -- node[above]{$f$} (B);
\path[draw, -latex'] (B) -- node[above]{$g$} (C);
\path[draw, -latex'] (C) -- node[above]{$h$} (D);
\path[draw, -latex', dashed] (A) -- node[below]{$g\circ f$} (C);
\path[draw, -latex', dashed] (B) -- node[below]{$h\circ g$} (D);
\path[draw, -latex', dashed] (A) -- node[below]{$h\circ (g\circ f)$} (D);
\path[draw, -latex', dashed] (A) to [bend right]  node[below]{$(h\circ g)\circ f$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]